# ios app runs perfectly in debug mode but crashes in release

Tags: ios, crash, release

My app crashes in certain moments in release build. I don't know if it is important but I use mainly c++ with cocos2d-x framework. I tried setting optimization level to none but it won't work too. I get this output in console :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: map::at:  key not found
```

This is part of the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3870d1f0 0x386fa000 + 78320
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38777792 0x38774000 + 14226
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x386bdfd8 0x38675000 + 298968
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x379eccd2 0x379ec000 + 3282
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37a056aa 0x379ec000 + 104106
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3814af86 0x38147000 + 16262
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37a031c4 0x379ec000 + 94660
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37a02d28 0x379ec000 + 93480
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3814ae12 0x38147000 + 15890
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2d3d2f80 0x2d3cb000 + 32640
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2d3d2cee 0x2d3cb000 + 31982
11  GraphicsServices                0x3230565e 0x322fc000 + 38494
12  UIKit                           0x2fd1e168 0x2fcb0000 + 450920
13  BumpRace iOS                    0x00044b1e 0x4000 + 264990
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x38657ab4 0x38656000 + 6836
```

Any help would be apprieciated.

Comment: are you generating any rand variable?

Answer (score 0):

You must use iOS instruments tool. To debug you memory leaks. As possible to conclude from youre ERROR message.

Small useful [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).